# как получить файл из network, используя java+selenium+webdriver

Tags: java, сеть, selenium, test-automation

Нужно получить файл из network, во вкладке Headers.
Из localStorage получаю значение переменной как-то так:

```
Object val = ((JavascriptExecutor) StoriesRunner.getWebDriver()).executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('search_counter')");
```

а как получать данные из network я не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете сначала такие настройки для драйвера и передаёте caps при создание объект WebDriver

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
```

Далее, например в самое тесте (или где вам надо) выполняете:

```
List<LogEntry> entries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll();
System.out.println(entries.size() + " " + LogType.PERFORMANCE + " log entries found");
for (LogEntry entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(
            new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
}
```